# I was wondering how to create several rows in a box using the fbox command in latex

Tags: latex

This is a very basic question, but I cant find the answer to this question....
I would like to create a box that looks like:

```
                          ___________________
                          |hello1            |
                          |hello2            |
                          |hello3            |
                          |__________________|
```

I have tried the fbox command in Latex. However I only get the text on one line and not several.

Comment: Hi, we now have a dedicated Q&A site for TeX questions. Please ask your question again at http://tex.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 13):

`\fbox` puts a frame round its content, but is not a paragraph box. So you need a `\parbox` inside an `\fbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
hello1\\
hello2\\
hello3
}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Also, if you append \noindent before \fbox , i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{%
hello1\\
hello2\\
hello3
}}
\end{document}
```

you can prevent indentation of the box.

Comment: This should be a comment to Joseph's solution.